# How to programmatically make a data frame from vectors with some name pattern

Tags: r, dataframe

I have multiple vector objects in my environments. The names of all these vectors contain the string "column" in them. For instance, I have vector objects called column_1, column_2, etc.

How do I programmatically make a data frame from all these vectors as the columns of the data frames without typing the names of the vectors?

and I don't want to simply say:

```r
data.frame(column_1, column_2, ...)
```

Is there any method using `apply()` or `do.call()` functions?

I have done this

```r
vec_list <- grep("column", ls(), value=T)
```

but this doesn't work

```r
data.frame(vec_list)
```

I expect the output to be one data frame with the vector objects as the columns of the data frame.

Comment: Use `data.frame(mget(ls(pattern = "column_\\d+")))` assuming vectors are of equal length

Comment: Yes, they're equal length. And that worked. Did not know much about the `mget` function but now I know. Thanks.

Comment: Where did these vectors come from? It's usually not a good idea to have a bunch of separate objects in your environment with differing suffixes. Typically those types of objects should be gathers in a list to begin with to make it easy to iterate or work with them. Seeing `get()` or `mget()` is a sign that things probably aren't being done in an R-like way.

Comment: You are totally right @MrFlick! However, for some reason the environment I import is like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have unequal length vectors, then you can use something like this-

**Sample Data-**

```
column_1 <- c("a","b","c")
column_2 <- c("a","b","c","d")
column_3 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6)

> data.frame(lapply(mget(ls(pattern = "column_\\d+")), "length<-", max(lengths(mget(ls(pattern = "column_\\d+"))))))

  column_1 column_2 column_3
1        a        a        1
2        b        b        2
3        c        c        3
4     <NA>        d        4
5     <NA>     <NA>        5
6     <NA>     <NA>        6
```

**Note**- Solution mentioned by **@akrun** is best, if you have equal length vectors.

```
data.frame(mget(ls(pattern = "column_\\d+")))
```